# Exposed .NET Object as COM - What happens with web.config

Tags: .net, com, asp-classic, com-interop

I have a .NET project that access the .config file (web.config typically) to get configuration information.

If I access this .NET project from a classic ASP application how does it handle reading data from the web.config or app.config?  Can it?

FYI - Using System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration

Comment: Are you trying to call into the compiled dll's of a ASP.NET web application that I am assuming you've exposed some code via COM? Or have you wrote a .NET library that is exposed as COM? I'm confused because you sound like you are trying to access the ASP.NET code directly via COM from an ASP site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the .NET code called via COM Interop will look for 'executable filename'.config in the same directory as executable filename, where the executable filename is the unmanaged exe (the calling process).

For classic ASP, this will probably be %WINDOWS%\system32\dllhost.exe.config - I have dim memories of doing something like this nearly a decade ago.

If you can modify the .NET project a better option might be to manage configuration settings in the classic ASP code and pass these through a new Configure interface on your .NET library. Or use another approach (like the registry, or loading your own config file).